# td cuts when page break to next page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had following issue

[image]

As you can see in image

1. data is not display properly
2. next `td` last character `3` is also print in next line
3. Can I avoid page footer and header without adjusting page margin?

I had google lot about this and find following solution but it does not work for me in at list google chrome and IE9

```
<style>
@media print
{
  body { font-size:small; font-family: myOpenSans, Tahoma; font-size:13px; color:#808080; display:table-row}
  table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Don't get your hopes up on this; after more than 20 years of web browsers, printing HTML is still in the stone ages :-( Usually, you will have to convert the data to PDF on the server to get the page layout that you need.

Comment: Right but they want direct print option they will not allow us to increase steps that download and print pdf yourself.

Comment: In that case, "they" should be happy with what they get. You can suggest to them to open a bug against IE. Maybe Microsoft would improve printing if they asked nicely.

Comment: Yes.. I have only that last option.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can open printing dialog from IE and predefine some values from activex control and remove page's footer and header and also set the margins if you want

```
    function printSpecial() {
        try {

            var html = '<HTML><HEAD>\n';
            if (document.getElementsByTagName != null) {
                var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
                if (headTags.length > 0)
                    html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
            }
            html += '<BODY style="background-color: #ffffff;">\n';
            var printReadyElem = document.getElementById('content');
            if (printReadyElem != null) {
                html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
            }
            else {
                alert('Could not find the printReady function');
                return;
            }
            html += '</BODY></HTML>';

            shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            shell.sendKeys('%fu'); //brings up page setup
            shell.sendKeys("%a{TAB}.2{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}{UP}{TAB}{UP}{TAB}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{TAB}{UP}{UP}{ENTER}");
            window.setTimeout("shell.SendKeys('%fp')",1000); // brings up print dialog
        } catch (e) {
            alert ("An exception occured: " + e + "\nCode is: " + e.number + "\nDescription is: " + e.description);
            alert('Please verify that your print settings have a Landscape orientation.');
        }
    }
```